# Given an ODBC connection string for a database, how can I modify my settings.py such that my Django app will connect to it?

Tags: python, django, django-pyodbc

I have been given an ODBC connection string to connect to a database. However, I am having difficulty in having my Django app to connect to it. What are the proper steps to have my app to connect to it? Am I missing anything in my code?

This is my connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};uid=user;pwd=secret;server=databasename;astart=No;host=127.0.0.1;port=1234
```

Using a test script that uses pyodbc I am able to connect to the database. However, when I attempt to modify the settings.py file for my app, it fails to connect to the database.

**Requirements.py**

```
django~=2.1.4
pyodbc~=4.0.25
django-pyodbc-azure~=2.1.0.0
```

**Settings.py**

```
#First Attempt
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1,1234',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret',
        'NAME': 'databasename',
        'PORT': '1234',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver' : 'SQL Anywhere 17',
            'host_is_server': 'True',
        },
    }
}

#Second Attempt
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '',
        'NAME': 'databasename;',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'host_is_server': 'True',
            'dsn': 'Driver={SQL Anywhere 17};uid=user;pwd=secret;server=databasename;astart=No;host=127.0.0.1;port=1234'
        },
    }
}
```

For my first attempt, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

For my second attempt, I am getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Benjamin! Give this a try:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "1234",
        "NAME": "databasename",
        "USER": "user",
        "PASSWORD": "secret",
        "AUTOCOMMIT": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "driver": "SQL Anywhere 17",
            "unicode_results": True,
            "host_is_server": True,
        },
    },
}
```

One key here is the `"driver"` setting. It has to match the title of the driver section in your `odbcinst.ini` file. For example, I have the following in my `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

In my case, I use: `"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",` in the `OPTIONS` dictionary, so it matches the heading title in the `odbcinst.ini` configuration file. This is where I've seen most people get tripped up. Good luck!

Comment: I should mention that I am using windows Powershell. Delving into my problem, I see that client is using SQL Anywhere 12. I have also located the ODBC.ini file and used "SQL Anywhere 12 CustDB" for the driver, leading to the following error: `django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`